# How to convert wide dataframe to long dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, append

I am trying to convert a wide dataframe [2r, 12c] to a long dataframe [4r,6c).

```
From this ...
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11  
0  1.0  0.9  0.8  0.5  0.4  0.3  0.7  0.9  0.2  0.1  0.4  0.3
1  0.6  0.8  0.5  0.3  0.7  0.1  0.4  0.2  0.8  0.6  0.4  0.1

... to this ...
   0    1    2    3    4    5       
0  1.0  0.9  0.8  0.5  0.4  0.3   
1  0.7  0.9  0.2  0.1  0.4  0.3  
2  0.6  0.8  0.5  0.3  0.7  0.1  
3  0.4  0.2  0.8  0.6  0.4  0.1
```

My code is producing unexpected results:

```
   0    1    2    3    4    5   6    7    8    9    10   11    
0  1.0  0.9  0.8  0.5  0.4  0.3 
1  Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan 0.7  0.9  0.2  0.1  0.4  0.3 
etc...
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(2, 12)
)

slice_sz = 6

x = df.columns
col_num = len(x)

col_iter = int(col_num / slice_sz)

y = df.index
row_num = len(y)

df_list = pd.DataFrame([])

for row in range(row_num):
    # print('Processing row', row)
    i = 0
    j = slice_sz - 1

    for col in range(col_iter):
        df_sliced = df.iloc[row, i:j]
        df_sliced = df_sliced.to_frame()
        df_sliced = df_sliced.transpose()
        df_list = df_list.append(df_sliced)
        df_sliced = []
        i += slice_sz
        j += slice_sz
```

I know there must be a more elegant way to do this.
Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 2):

If you do not care for pandas, I would do something like this:

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(2, 12)

# reshape is your friend! 
data_transformed = data.reshape(4,6)
```

Please checkout `numpy.reshape` documentation here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Although if you really, really, really want to reshape a dataframe (although I'm not sure why you would want to), you can do this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(2, 12)
)

df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().reshape(4,6))
```

Which really all I did there was convert the dataframe into a numpy array, reshape, and set the numpy array back to a dataframe.

Comment: That one line of code works perfectly with random floats, but I noticed you used .to_numpy() within the reshape line. What if it has mixed types? I'll look into .reshape now. Thank you!

Comment: I've tested the reshape method
```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().reshape(4,6))
```
and it appears to work effectively on all data types. So mission accomplished.
Thank you Ryno_XLI!

Comment: Glad to hear, reshape is very useful and I use it frequently. If you google "numpy reshape" you should find good resources. For example, `.reshape(-1,6)` and `.reshape(4,-1)` would be exactly the same as `.reshape(4,6)` since the original shape is (2,12). Reshape is just inferring for the "-1" value the number of rows needed if you give it a 6 for the number of columns (and vice-versa for the inputs of (4,-1)).

Answer (score 0):

For the code above, I would use `df_list.pivot()`

Within the `.pivot()` you will need to specify `index = ''`, `columns = ''` and `values = ''`. There is plenty of info around on `.pivot()` should you require any further clarification.

This function will help with either a wide-to-long or a long-to-wide transpose of your dataframe.

This should do away with the for loop you put together to undertake this task.

Comment: I looked a .pivot() and .melt() (and .wide_to_long() as well) and couldn't figure out how to use them. I'll look at these again. Thank you!

Comment: No sweat. Throw an upvote up if the answer is ok.